# Implementing Kernel in C and Shell in C#

Tags: process, client-server, inter-process-communicat

Is it possible to implement MVC architecture's control in one language and view in other language.
What I'm looking for is a pattern to have a "kernel" in C and the "shell" in C#.
Or like "server" in C and "client" in C# (but in the same machine).
Only approach I come up with is to use pipes or sockets to communicate between the two processes.
Is there a better approach ? (I'm sure there is but What is it ? )

**Eidt :** I found a number of approaches [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx).but wonder what would be the ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared memory might be a solution: [MSDN - Creating Named Shared Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But beware that dealing with shared memory is a LOT trickier than dealing with "higher level" constructs like sockets.

Cheers. Keith.